# Maya Python UI - Show an Objects ClassParent Class When Selected

Tags: python, class, user-interface, parent, maya

Hello I need some help I'm a novice when it comes to advanced python coding, I've been trying to solve this problem but I'm unable to find an answer. I'm trying to find a way so that when someone clicks on an object inside Maya for example a basic sphere it will print the object class and parent class into each of the textFields; then should a user select something else like a cube it will instead show that object class&parent class. I know I need a function which will activate when an object is selected then place the value into the textFields, but I can't figure out how to do it. If anyone has a solution it would be greatly appreciated :)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

class drawUI(): #Function that will draw the entire window
        #check to see if window exists
    if cmds.window("UI_MainWindow", exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI("UI_MainWindow")
        #create actual window
    cmds.window("UI_MainWindow", title = "User Interface Test", w = 500, h = 700, mnb = False, mxb = False, sizeable = False)
    cmds.columnLayout("UI_MainLayout", adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.text(label="Object's Class:")
    ObjClass = cmds.textField(text = cmds.objectType,editable = False)
    cmds.text(label="Object's Parent Class:")
    ObjParClass = cmds.textField(editable = False)
    cmds.showWindow("UI_MainWindow") #shows window
```

Answer (score 0):

The main stumbling block is that you're using the class setup in a very unusual way. The usual pattern is to have an `__init__` method that creates a new copy ("instance") of the class; in you case you're executing the code when the class is *defined* rather than when you invoke it. The usual class shell looks like:

```
class Something (object) # derive from object in python 2.7, ie, in maya
    def __init__(self):
       self.variable = 1 # set persistent variables for the object
       do_something()  # other setup runs now, when a new Something is created
    def method(self):
       print self.variable # you can use any variables defined in 'self'
```

The usual way to create a reactive UI in maya is to use a [scriptJob](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/scriptJob.html).  These will fire a script callback when certain events happen inside of Maya. The easiest event for your purpose is `SelectionChanged` which fires when the selection changes.

The other thing you want to do is figure out how to pack this into a class. Sometimes it's a good idea to create your class object and then give it a `show()` or `layout()` method that creates the actual UI -- a lot depends on how much you need to set the object up before showing the window.

In this case I put the behavior into the `__init__` so it will create the UI when you make the object.  The `__init__` also creates the scriptJob and parents it to the window (so it will disappear when the window does).

```
class drawUI(object):

    def __init__(self):

        if cmds.window("UI_MainWindow", exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI("UI_MainWindow")
            #create actual window
        self.window = cmds.window("UI_MainWindow", title = "User Interface Test", w = 500, h = 700, mnb = False, mxb = False, sizeable = False)
        cmds.columnLayout("UI_MainLayout", adjustableColumn=True)
        cmds.text(label="Object's Class:")
        self.ObjClass = cmds.textField(text = cmds.objectType,editable = False)
        cmds.text(label="Object's Parent Class:")
        self.ObjParClass = cmds.textField(editable = False)
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)
        cmds.scriptJob (e = ("SelectionChanged", self.update_UI), p= self.window)

    def update_UI(self, *_, **__):
        sel = cmds.ls(selection=True) or []
        c = ["-none-", "-none-"]
        if sel:
            c = cmds.nodeType(sel[0], i = True)
        cmds.textField(self.ObjClass, e=True, text = c[-1])
        cmds.textField(self.ObjParClass, e=True, text = ", ".join(c[:-1]))

test = drawUI()
```

By using `self.update_UI` without arguments in the scriptJob, we make sure that the function that fires knows which object it's updating.  Using the self variables for the textfields lets us update the UI that goes with the window without worrying about remembering names in some other scope.

[More details here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)

Comment: Thank for help, but now I have a problem. I tried to incorporate it with some of my other code, don't get any error msgs but the window doesn't appear why could this be?